# how to assign a pandas.core.series.Series to a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assing a `pandas.core.series.Series` to a pandas dataframe column.

First I create a function:

```
####################################### set month #################################
import datetime
import pandas as pd

actual_date = datetime.now()
actual_date = datetime.strptime("{}/{}/{}".format('01', actual_date.month, actual_date.year), "%d/%m/%Y")

def set_date(actual_date):
    result = actual_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    print(datetime.strftime(result, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Then I apply it over a pandas df an define this as `pd_object` which returns a `pandas.core.series.Series` type which contains `set_date()` output:

```
pd_object = pd.Series(df.apply(lambda x: set_date(actual_date), axis=1));
```

Then when I assign it to a new col `df['month']=pd_object` it returns me a pandas dataframe column full of `None` rows, when the expected result has to be `set_date()` output over these rows.

How could I assign `pd_object` to a new pandas dataframe column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set_date` function only prints, yet does not return anything, i.e. `None`. That's why you get all the `None`. Maybe you mean:

```
def set_date(actual_date):
    result = actual_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    return datetime.strftime(result, "%d/%m/%Y")

# your `apply` code seems to return a single, constant value for the whole dataframe
# you can just let Pandas broadcast that to the whole data
df['month'] = set_date(actual_date)
```